# wavesurfer.js doesn't play before loading is completed on safari

Tags: audio, safari

I've set up a wavesurfer audio model, which is working perfectly fine on chrome and firefox. It starts right away. When I want hit play on safari it waits for the whole file to be downloaded complete and only then it plays...I've experienced a similar problem on other pages that I open on safari as well....any ideas, why this could be the case and what to against it?

```
    audioModel = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: createdContainer,
    waveColor: waveColor,
    progressColor: waveColorProg,
    height: height,
    backend: 'MediaElement',
    cursorWidth:0,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the bug https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/1215

Try the work around proposed by DrLongGhost which uses MediaElement in Safari (only). Other browsers work better with WebAudio backend. https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/1215#issuecomment-415083308

```
// Only use MediaElement backend for Safari
const isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent || '') ||
      /iPad|iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent || '');

const wavesurferArgs = {
      container: document.getElementById('wavesurferContainerInternal'),
      plugins
};
if (isSafari) {
      wavesurferArgs.backend = 'MediaElement';
}
_wavesurfer = window.WaveSurfer.create(wavesurferArgs);
```

Update: ah you already are using MediaElement. We'll I'm not sure what the problem is.